# Prompt a different client from remote server

Tags: c#, wcf, remote-access

I have come up with the situation like:

From the client, I (USER A) am calling the service, the service has to do for example 4 steps, the fourth step  depends on the third one. Now when first 2 are done the 3rd will go to database and fetch the value and now the service has to go to another user (user D who did not initiate the process) prompt him with yes or no (or whatever). When he clicks on yes then it will come back and do the 4th step.

How can I achieve this situation?
Actually, the thing is how to go from the server to the different user?

I am using WCF (C#.NET) and SQL Server with Ext JS in UI.

Thanks

Comment: So you are trying to create work-flows? There are a lot of questions that need to be answered i.e. Is the "sign-off" user always going to be "logged in" to a browser? Can the sign-off happen "out of band" (user A starts work flow, user D gets notification, but doesn't agree until hours later), if so then you need some form of state...

Comment: yes the user D will be logged in. User A will initiate the process. Can it be done with Impersonation or there are better ways to do.

Comment: Impersonation won't be able to achieve what you are after. It's unlikely you'll get any complete answers from SO as you're asking for an entire solution.... But I would probably start looking at SignalR (http://signalr.net/) for notifcation delivery etc. If that doesn't fit, then K2 (http://www.k2.com/platform/workflow-software) might fit. Aside from that it really comes down to your design.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments

Comment: Don't think it would be easy to do with WCF as it can be with SignalR

Comment: Can I use SignalR with WCF. Also my UI is in Extjs.